# issues with clearing setTimeout() in javascript code

Tags: javascript, dom, cleartimeout

I am trying to make a button which when clicked will stop the execution of the automatic slideshow. 
The clearTimeout() function isn't working for some strange reason. can someone please tell me how to make it work?

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click",stop);
function stop(){
  **clearTimeout(t);**
}

window.addEventListener("load",finalResult);

**var t = setTimeout(function(){finalResult()},0);**

function finalResult(){
  getFirstImage();

  function getFirstImage(){
   img1.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(getSecondImage,3000);
}

 function getSecondImage(){
    img1.style.display = "none";
    img2.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(getThirdImage,3000);
  }

 function getThirdImage(){
  img3.style.display = "block";
  img2.style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(getFourthImage,3000);
}

 function getFourthImage(){
  img4.style.display = "block";
  img3.style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(loopAgain,3000);
}

function loopAgain(){
  img4.style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(getFirstImage,0);
}


}
```

Comment: You've set the timeout to 0 so there's no way you click before it happens.

Comment: are you expecting clearing `t` to clear all the other times outs (`setTimeout(getFirstImage,0);`) you've set? because it won't. You need to clear each timeout individually

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear all the timeouts present in the page.

Something like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", stop);

function stop() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  clearTimeout(a);
  clearTimeout(b);
  clearTimeout(c);
  clearTimeout(d);
  clearTimeout(e);
}

window.addEventListener("load", finalResult);

var t = setTimeout(function() {
  finalResult()
}, 100);

var a, b, c, d, e;

function finalResult() {
  getFirstImage();

  function getFirstImage() {
    img1.style.display = "block";
     a = setTimeout(getSecondImage, 3000);
  }

  function getSecondImage() {
    img1.style.display = "none";
    img2.style.display = "block";
    b = setTimeout(getThirdImage, 3000);
  }

  function getThirdImage() {
    img3.style.display = "block";
    img2.style.display = "none";
    c = setTimeout(getFourthImage, 3000);
  }

  function getFourthImage() {
    img4.style.display = "block";
    img3.style.display = "none";
    d = setTimeout(loopAgain, 3000);
  }

  function loopAgain() {
    img4.style.display = "none";
    e = setTimeout(getFirstImage, 0);
  }
}
```